# Pass values to formula (containing String and Arithmetic operatores) stored in MySQL column and do calculations

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to do calculations based on Formula stored in Table as VARCHAR, for example, "100*BasicVal" and pass some value like 100 to string part of variable "BasicVal" as 1000.

I have tried to work on, and clearly, it's not the way. Please suggest a way for implementation. Trim won't work in my case as sometimes the formula may go as long as 4-5 Variable parts and operations. The code that I tried on my test table is following. It will help you to understand what I am trying to get.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `tester`()
begin

DECLARE VALUE0 varchar(50);
DECLARE VALUE1 INT;
DECLARE BasicVal INT;    

select @valueC1:=C1 from tester where id = '1'; 

SET BasicVal = 1000;
SET VALUE0 = @valueC1;
SET VALUE1 = CAST(VALUE0 AS SIGNED );

INSERT IGNORE INTO TESTER (C1) VALUES(VALUE1);

 end
```

Please note that Row returned from `"select @valueC1:=C1 from tester where id = '1';"` is 100*BasicVal

I clearly understand the code above makes no practical sense as I am trying to convert String to INT, see this code just to understand my requirement.

Comment: Is it true to say that any string after an operator and before the end of the formula or before the next numeric value should be substituted with a parameter passed to the procedure and further we can assume the parameters passed will be in the substitution order required by the formula?

Comment: All the values passed will have some variable name as for every distinct STRING part of Formula string, like if I extend the above-mentioned formula in the example, next example may be "(100*BasicVal)*(1/BasicVal2)". So, I may already have 2 variables (existing/declared) BasicVal and BasicVal2 and they must be having some integer value and I need to pass those values to "(100*BasicVal)*(1/BasicVal2)" and get INT value as result.